# Force OSGi service be reloaded

Tags: java, osgi

Assume I have 2 OSGi services. One of them is memory cache of DB records. Another service is set of [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on these DB records. During modification I would like to rebuild existing cache. How one service can force another be MODIFIED? Something like to send `org.osgi.framework.ServiceEvent.MODIFIED` event.

(please note that it is simplified example of real business case and I don't really place cache as a service)

**UPDATE** to make question more clear - I need exactly same function as `ServiceRegistration#setProperties` provides. Unfortunately `ServiceRegistration` should not leave bound of Bundle.

Comment: provide an operation in the OSGi service interface to rebuild the cache? this is not really related to OSGi - your component has an internal cache, so you want to provide a way in the interface to rebuild it.

Comment: well, if I would really use cache as service - then yes. But I just figured out the problem - one service need force MODIFY another one (in OSGI terms)

Comment: to me that sounds like a code smell, one osgi service should not be sending registration events on the behalf of another.

Comment: @eis well, fully agree that OSGi not suitable, but scenario is really agile - DB was changed, bundle/service need be notified on this. So what is your proposition to avoid "code smell"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to solve this using services?

Simply send an event using EventAdmin from the CRUD bundle that says that data is modified. So the cache can listen to these events and act accordingly. The advantage of the eventing solution is that the crud service does not really have to know there is a cache it just sends the event to whoever is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Please, please don't try to do this.

Only the provider bundle for the service knows what implementation is behind it... that is why only the provider has access to the registration details.

The cache provider should detect *for itself* whether the underlying data has changed, and refresh the cache appropriately. No other bundle(s) can do this because they have no idea where the cache provider gets its data, they can only see the public service interface.

Comment: *"should detect for itself whether the underlying data has changed,"* - so you propose watch-dog pattern? No, obviously exists better solution - some event bus. Writer notifies cache on changes and it is fast and reliable. But this solution unfortunately is not part of OSGi.

Comment: In the alternate, the cache provider service could have a method which others can call to request the cache be rebuilt.